# jQuery doesn't return any API results in the Succes function of $.ajax() while using JSONP

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter, jsonp

I'm having a lot of trouble getting any results out of the JSONP datatype of the jQuery $.ajax() function. This is my jQuery code:

```
  $('#show_tweets').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
      type: 'get',
      url: 'http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=jquery',
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      succes: function(data) {
        $.each(data, function() {
          $('<div></div>')
            .hide()
            .append('<img src="'+ this.profile_image_url +'"/>')
            .append('<p>'+ this.text +'</p>')
            .appendTo('#tweets_gallery')
            .fadeIn();
        })
      },
      error: function() {
        alert('Iets gaat fout!!');
      }
    });
  });
```

I've assigned the #show_tweets ID to a P tag. #tweets_gallery is an empty DIV. Now, I **know** I could also use the $.getJSON() function, but I just want to know how I can properly retrieve JSONP results with a **$.ajax()** request. I've clicked several times and it doesn't output anything.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: check this website :) it will help http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/

Comment: jsonp: 'jsonp_callback', instead of  dataType: 'jsonp',

Answer (score 0):

In case it's an error because of your typo:

`succes: function(data)` should be `success: function(data)`

In reply to your comment below, the reason `profile_image_url` is undefined is because there is no property in the root scope. The JSON returned from twitter is in the form of:

```
{
  "text" : "The twitter text",
  "user" : {
           "profile_image_url" : "http://path.to.profileimage/",
           ...
  },
  ...
}
```

So `this.text` exists (which is why you get the value) but you should be accessing the profile image as `this.user.profile_image_url`

See the [twitter API](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/user_timeline) for how the JSON is structured.

Comment: LOL, that was exactly the problem! You have a keen eye, sir! Okay, I have one last question though: my AJAX request doesn't return anything useful when I define "this.profile_image_url". "this.text" works perfectly though. "this.profile_image_url" however, remains literally undefined. I'm expecting to see the jQuery avatar popping up in this case. Have I got the wrong scope for this?

Comment: @Martijn1981 It's because the profile image is under the `user` object in the data that your reading. I've updated my answer in response to your comment.